# Custom method for Web API which is not standard CRUD methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I notice that most of the web api tutorial just mention the CRUD methods. My question is what about those method which is not CRUD? Example, if I have a model for Employee with these following properties: Id, Name, Email, Username and Password. For the admin module, for `update employee function`, there is no problem because the web api will be in CRUD. For example below:

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

// PUT api/Employee/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutEmployee(int id, Employee employee)
    {

        if (id != employee.EmployeeID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EmployeeExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

But for employee module, what about `change password` function? Do I need to create another controller with `put` verb just for each function?

I found an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1277140/Simple-Transaction-Microservices-Sample-Architectu) which is related to my question. How do I create a custom method like deposit (httppost) and witdrawal (httppost) for an ATM program?

Comment: If I get it right, you need to ask yourself who trigger a specific action (reset PWD). If it is user then put that responsibility within usercontroller or if it is admin then put it within admin controller. Now if reset pwd have multiple triggering points such as user/admin resting password then you can extract the reset logic and inject it into user and admin controlller.

Comment: Are you asking about a customer entity or an actual customer human who will be manipulating an employee entity? If you are dealing with a customer entity then I would create a separate controller for customer methods.

Comment: Sorry I mean employee for the first one. For second atm example I use is customer

Comment: I mean custom method

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. If you feel that the password is a resource of itself, then you can have the following:

`PUT` `api/customer/{id}/password`

That would become in your controller

```
public IHttpActionResult PutCustomerPassword(int id, Password password)
```

If the password is just a string in Customer, then update the Customer sendind the new password in the `Employee` object.

You can ofcourse use inheritance, creating a new base Controller, that has some user management functionality and share between the Employee and the Customer. This way you can use the CustomerController and EmployeeController just as an entry point and call the BaseController code to do the actual work.